# How can I deal with Expect data.index as DatetimeIndex?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mplfinance

I am planning to get a candlestick plot from the bitcoin data.
Here is my code for select the dataframe I want after loading the csv file.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
start_date = '2016-02-27'
end_date = '2021-02-27'
mask = (df['Date'] >= start_date) & (df['Date'] <= end_date)
df = df.loc[mask]
df
```

and then, I entered the code for making the candlestick plot like below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
! pip install --upgrade mplfinance
import mplfinance as mpf
import matplotlib.dates as mpl_dates


mpf.plot(df, type = 'candle', style = 'charles',
        title = 'Bitcoin Price',
        ylabel = 'Price (USD$)',
        volume = True,
        ylabel_lower = 'Shares \nTraded',
        mav = (3,6,9),
        savefig = 'chart-mplfinance.png')
```

It said "TypeError: Expect data.index as DatetimeIndex".
So I looked up the solution for this on google and I tried out this:

```
df = dict()
df['Date'] = []
df['High'] = []
df['Low'] = []
df['Open'] = []
df['Close'] = []
df['Volume'] = []
for dict in df:
    df['Date'].append(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    df['High'].append(dict['High'])
    df['Low'].append(dict['Low'])
    df['Open'].append(dict['Open'])
    df['Close'].append(dict['Close'])
    df['Volume'].append(dict['Vol'])
print("df:", df)
pdata = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df) 
pdata.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
mpf.plot(pdata)
```

This time, it said "invalid syntax"
I'm not sure where I get this wrong, is there anything that I have missed?

Answer (score 19):

There are two easy ways to make sure your dataframe has a `pandas.DatetimeIndex` as the dataframe index:

1. When calling `read_csv()` indicate which column you want to use for the index (which should *be* the column that contains the dates/datetimes), and also set kwarg `parse_dates=True`.
    
   This will will automatically convert the datetimes column (which is normally strings within a csv file) into a `DatetimeIndex` object, *and set it as the index*
    
   You can see this being done in the examples in the mplfinance repository, [**for example, click here, and look under basic usage**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance#basic-usage) where you can see **`index_col=0, parse_dates=True`** in the call to `read_csv()`.
2. Use the `pandas.DatetimeIndex()` constructor.
    
   For example, **instead of** what you wrote,
   `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`, **you would write:**

```py
    df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date'])
```

---

As a side note, once the dataframe has a DatetimeIndex, you don't need the `mask` in the next section of code, but can simply **slice** as follows:

```py
start_date = '2016-02-27'
end_date   = '2021-02-27'
df = df.loc[start_date:end_date]
```

hth.