# Stumped. How do I convert my datetime format to an acceptable format for pandas and mplfinance?

Tags: dataframe, indexing, datetimeindex, mplfinance, ohlc

I am trying to use various charting packages for ohlc bar charting.  Some success but I keep getting stuck on "TypeError: Expect data.index as DatetimeIndex".  The samples that I copy work perfectly fine, like this below:

```py
import yfinance as yf
import mplfinance as mpf
symbol = 'AAPL'
df = yf.download(symbol, period='6mo')
mpf.plot(df, type='candle')
```

which has the following type of index for the df :

```py
DatetimeIndex(['2022-06-30', '2022-07-01', '2022-07-05', '2022-07-06',
               '2022-12-29', '2022-12-30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', length=128, freq=None)
```

So I am trying to get my dataframe index to look the same, with a DatetimeIndex format.  My index looks like this:

```py
0       2022-11-09 14:30:00+00:00
1       2022-11-09 14:35:00+00:00
2       2022-11-09 14:40:00+00:00
3       2022-11-09 14:45:00+00:00
4       2022-11-09 14:50:00+00:00
                  ...            
2299    2022-12-21 20:35:00+00:00
2300    2022-12-21 20:40:00+00:00
2301    2022-12-21 20:45:00+00:00
2302    2022-12-21 20:50:00+00:00
2303    2022-12-21 20:55:00+00:00
Name: date, Length: 2304, dtype: object
```

Note the default integer index on left.   I believe that I dont need to format it exactly the same, as long the internal datatype being datetime64 in a DatetimeIndex form.

thanks for any help.

So I tried this ( and whole lot of other ideas)

```py
    df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
    new = pd.DataFrame(index=[df.timestamp])
```

which gives

```py
MultiIndex([('2022-11-09 14:30:00+00:00',),
            ...
            ('2022-12-21 20:55:00+00:00',)],
           names=['timestamp'], length=2304)
```

as well as this:

```py
 df['timestamp'] = mpl_dates.datestr2num(df.date)
```

which gives:

```py
MultiIndex([(19305.604166666668,),
            ( 19305.60763888889,),

            (19347.868055555555,),
            (19347.871527777777,)],
           names=['timestamp'], length=2304)
```

and neither work.

Am I on the right track, and what is the correct way to do this? How do I get rid of the MultiIndex? And how do I get it to be of type DatetimeIndex?

---

responding to the question on source of data, its from IBKR, using API routines and I am storing the data in an intermediary CSV file.  It has the following format:

> ,date,open,high,low,close,volume,barCount,average 0,2022-11-09
> 14:30:00+00:00,174.44,174.44,173.8,174.05,994,64,174.408 1,2022-11-09
> 14:35:00+00:00,174.11,174.38,173.58,173.62,160,123,173.95 2,2022-11-09
> 14:40:00+00:00,173.59,173.6,173.14,173.56,98,73,173.363 3,2022-11-09
> 14:45:00+00:00,173.55,174.02,173.52,173.96,88,53,173.716

I was reading in with the following:
`bars = pd.read_csv(name, header=0, index_col=0, sep=",")

Comment: It would be helpful if you would post exactly what your dataframe looks like, and perhaps indicate where you got the data for your dataframe.  At the very least, call **`df.to_csv("filename.csv")`** and post "filename.csv" somewhere for us to pick up.  Then, you yourself, re-read "filename.csv" using **`ndf = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")`** so that we are on the same page.  And then try from there.

Comment: See also this answer: **https://stackoverflow.com/a/67228213/1639359**,  perhaps that will help

Comment: Good question, and thanks for pointing me to the other answer.  I believe that has me making progress now.

Comment: I have modified the CSV read to  "bars= pd.read_csv(name, header=0, index_col=1, sep=",", parse_dates=True)" and that has helped greatly.   That did to the dataframe what I was looking for, and hopefully the charting routines will work now. Thanks Daniel Goldfarb for pointing me in that direction, I was getting lost on the conversion methods.