# mplfinance TypeError: Expect data.index as DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, mplfinance

```
data = pd.read_csv("AUDCAD.csv", header=0, index_col=0, sep=",", parse_dates=True)

mpf.plot(data, type='candle')
```

Dont know what is wrong in my code or in data that when I try to plet getting

```
TypeError: Expect data.index as DatetimeIndex
```

Any advise will be highly appreciated............... Thank

[image]`

this is how my data looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly, although you said `parsedates=True`, it is possible that something in your index column prevented at least one date from being parsed as a date.  If one row can't be parsed as a date, then pandas will likely decide to keep the entire column as strings.   You can check this by looking at the type of index you now have:

```py
data = pd.read_csv("AUDCAD.csv", header=0, index_col=0, 
                   sep=",", parse_dates=True)
print(type(data.index))
print(data.index)
```

If you don't have a DatetimeIndex, then you will need to convert it to a datetime index.  See also [How can I deal with Expect data.index as DatetimeIndex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67225879/how-can-i-deal-with-expect-data-index-as-datetimeindex?rq=2) for further details.  This can sometimes happen if there is a stray character somewhere in the column.  I am wondering also (but I don't know for sure) if the fact that your dates do not *all* have the same time zone offset is a problem for pandas to parse the dates correct.  Let me know if this information helps.